# How to find the difference of subsequent number from a array/list in scala?

Tags: scala

I am trying to get the difference of subsequent numbers from an array/list. Please see below code

```
val listValue= List(10,2,6,9)

val result= Array(listValue).sliding(2).map(r => r(1) - r(0)).toList
```

If I pass the integer value to the array directly as `Array(10,2,6,9)`, I would get the result as follows: `8,4,3`, But when I pass the argument `(listValue)` as seen above, I am getting following error:

> Error:(18, 59) value - is not a member of List[Int]
>       val result= Array(listValue).sliding(2).map(r => r(1) - r(0)).toList

It would be appreciated if anyone can help on this?

Answer (score 3):

`Array(listValue)` type is `Array[List[Int]]`
So you are trying to subtract 2 lists not 2 integers

you can do it directly over the list:

```
val listValue= List(10,2,6,9)
val result= listValue.sliding(2).map(r => r(1) - r(0)).toList
```

Comment: Don't forget assertion, that `listValue.size >= 2`. Otherwise, `sliding` can produce an 1-item `List` when the input itself is an `1-item` list

Comment: Another alternative to the `map` above is `map(List(a, b) => b - a)`

Comment: To avoid having to explicitly check the list length, you can use `collect` instead of `map`.  `val result = listValue.sliding(2).collect{case l::r::Nil => Math.abs(r - l)}.toList`.  I threw in the `Math.abs` based on your expected result set (all positive values).

Comment: @ygor Your suggestion does not work, you would need to use `map{case List(a, b) => b - a}`

Comment: @Shane's comment seems like the most elegant (and correct) answer